# How to check before using array's items?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 191
            [name] => Ali
            [range] => today
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 190
            [name] => John
            [range] => today
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 189
            [name] => peter
            [range] => in last week
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 180
            [name] => Ali
            [range] => in last week
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 170
            [name] => Jack
            [range] => in last week
        )
)
*/
```

And I'm trying to make a HTML dynamically like this:

```
<div id = "notification_box">
    <div class= "cases">
        <div class="title">today</div>                        
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>191</td>
                <td>Ali</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>190</td>
                <td>John</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class= "cases">
        <div class="title">yesterday</div>                   
    </div>
    <div class= "cases">
        <div class="title">in last week</div>    
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>189</td>
                <td>Peter</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>180</td>
                <td>Ali</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>170</td>
                <td>Jack</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Here is my code:

```
$html = '';
$last_item_range = '';

foreach ( $results as $key => $item )
{
  $next_item = ( is_array($results[$key+1]) ) ? $results[$key+1] : null;

    if ( $item['range'] != $last_item_range )
    {
        $html .= '<div class="cases">';
        $html .=   sprintf('<div class="title">%s</div>', $item['range']);
        $html .=   '<table>';

        $last_item_range = $item['range'];
    }

    $html .= '<tr>';
    foreach($item as $value){ $html .= sprintf('<td>%s</td>', $value); }
    $html .= '</tr>';

    if ( $next_item['range'] != $item['range'] )
    {
      $html .=  '</table>';
      $html .= '</div>';
    }
}

echo $html;
```

But this line `$results[$key+1]` throws this notice:

> **Notice:** Undefined offset

How can I fix it?

Also may you please tell me I'm do that correctly? Or there is a better algorithm to make that HTML?

Comment: Perhaps using `isset($results[$key+1]` rather than `is_array($results[$key+1]`

Comment: @MarkBaker Well played .. Just may you also please tell me I'm do that correctly? Or should I do that the other way?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a better way of setting the number of columns in pure css, but I'm not an expert in css

Comment: Foreach will iterate trough all elements. Once it reaches the last and you try getting the one after, it's obvious that it'd throw that error.

Comment: @MarkBaker What do you mean *"the number of columns"* exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution using two loops

```
$new_list =  array();
foreach( $array_list as  $list )
$new_list[$list['range']][] = $list;

?>
<div id="notification_box">
   <?php foreach( $new_list as $item_name => $items ): ?> 
    <div class= "cases">
        <div class="title"><?php echo $item_name ?></div>
        <?php 
          if( $items && is_array( $items )  ) {

             ?>
              <table>
                 <?php foreach( $items  as $item ): ?>
                 <tr>
                   <td><?php echo $item['id'] ?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $item['name'] ?></td>
                 </tr>
                 <?php endforeach; ?> 
              </table>
             <?php 

          }    
         ?>
    </div>
   <?php endforeach; ?> 
</div>
```

See complete result: https://3v4l.org/CHpm9

Comment: Accept this answer It might be helpful to others